# How to create an index page in a XSLT file

Tags: xsl-fo

I m new to XSL. I want to create a PDF using xsl-fO. In my PDF there are  sections like

1. General
2. Construction of Vehicle
3. Bodywork

I want to display an index of this section at the start of the PDF. I tried the following code in xsl but it is not working. It displays only "**Construction of Vehicle**"

```
<fo:block>Construction of Vehicle
  <fo:index-page-citation-list>
    <fo:index-key-reference ref-index-key="Construction of Vehicle"/>
  </fo:index-page-citation-list>
</fo:block>
```

Is there any other way to get indexing in XSL.
Please Suggest..

Comment: Please help me to find out solution.

Comment: The [XSL-FO recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#d0e9829) contains an example showing how to build a **table of contents**, which should be what you are looking for; note that an **index** is something different (it tells all the pages where a particular term appears in).

Comment: lfurini,thanks for ur response...actuly i want to display "1.Construction of Vehicle" word appear on which page of PDF...like wise all sections appears on which page.please suggest me....

Comment: The link I posted should give you an idea of the general technique; if you need more specific help, [edit] your question to include a *reduced* version of your input XML file and the XSLT you are using (see also [mcve]).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a table of contents.

You generally create this by placing a unique number in each section. In my case, the XML already contains a unique number I can use (the idRef attribute), otherwise you can use generate-id to create a unique number.

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <fo:block id="{@idRef}"/>
    <!--section content goes here-->
</xsl:template>
```

Then the TOC is a series of links to each ID:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/manual/chapter">
    <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@idRef}"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></fo:basic-link><!-- copies the section title-->
    <fo:basic-link internal-destination="{@idRef}"><fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{@idRef}"/></fo:basic-link><!-- generates the page number of the section-->
```